# import module with class methods

Tags: python, import-module

I am trying to get the docstring of class methods using import module and getattr. I have done the following previously:

```
getattr(import_module('string'),'capwords').__doc__
```

Which worked as expected?
Now I try to do the same with class methods and used [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) as an example

```
getattr(import_module('string','Formatter'),'format').__doc__
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'format'
```

How do I acquire the doc string of a class method.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you doing this? Why are you using `import_module` and `getattr` at all, since you have the names you want to import as constants already? And what makes you think the `string` module has a `format` attribute?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? What answer do you expect to get besides that the module does not have the attribute `'format'`?

Comment: Please check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel like you are trying

```
getattr(getattr(import_module('string'),'Formatter'), 'format').__doc__
```

OR

```
from operator import attrgetter
attrgetter("Formatter.format")(import_module("string")).__doc__
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the docstring of the [`string.Formatter.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method, you can do:

```
from string import Formatter

doc = Formatter.format.__doc__
```

Comment: My specific question was how to use import module with class methods